# Method to print odd numbers between 1 and 100

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, while-loop

I have to write a method that returns/prints the odd numbers between 1 and 100, but I have to use another method, which checks whether a given integer is odd or not:

```
static boolean isOdd(int c) {
    boolean d;
    d = c % 2 != 0;
    return d;
}
```

I'm guessing that I have to use either a for- or while-loop (probably can be done with both?), but I think what I'm really struggling with is "connecting" both methods. So the numbers actually run through isOdd() which determines whether they are odd.

I've tried these two options so far, but they're not working.
Option 1:

```
static void func1() {
    int number = 1;
    while (number < 100 && isOdd(number)) {
        System.out.println(number);
        number = number + 1;
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
static void func1() {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        isOdd(i);
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: In option 1 you stop looping as soon as you encounter a number that isn't odd, solution: Do not put the isOdd condition as your loop condition. Your loop condition is only running from 1 to 100 and nothing else. And in option 2 you loop from 1 to 100, call the isOdd method and do nothing with the result and just ignore it and then after the loop is done you print i, which will be 100. Option 2 is logically just completly wrong and currently equivalent to just printing 100. You need to print inside the loop and make printing conditional on the return value of your isOdd method call.

Comment: Instead of `boolean d;
        d = c % 2 != 0;
        return d;` you can write `return c % 2 != 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing that I have to use either a for- or while-loop (probably can be done with both?)

Yes. `for`-loops are just syntactic sugar for special `while`-loops:

```java
for (init_stmt; cond; incr_stmt) body_stmt;
```

is equivalent to

```java
init_stmt;
while (cond) {
    body_stmt;
    incr_stmt;
}
```

Let's first write this using a `for`-loop.

#### `for`-loop

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    if (isOdd(i))
        System.out.println(i)
```

Note that we can (and should!) do the *declaration* of `i` as `int` in the `for`-loop initializer.

Now, we may translate this to an equivalent `while`-loop:

#### `while`-loop

```java
int i = 1;
while (i < 100) {
    if (isOdd(i))
        System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

#### Mistakes in your attempts

##### Attempt 1

You've mistakenly included the check in the condition (rather than using it in an `if` inside the loop body); the first even number (`2`) will cause the loop to terminate.

##### Attempt 2

You're not even using the return value of `isOdd` here. You're unconditionally printing `i` *after* the loop has terminated, which will always be `100`.

#### The ideal implementation

Ideally, you'd not be filtering the numbers; you'd directly be incrementing by 2 to get to the next number. The following loop does the job:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: I would not call it "ideal" implementation - because it depends. Many ways lead to rome: `System.out.println("1\n3\n5\n7\n9\n13\n15\n17\n19\n21\n...");` - you get the idea. Why not skip loops at all? This is also not the "ideal" implementation, don't get me wrong please.

Comment: @cyberbrain Granted, ideal might depend on your requirements. Still, given the requirement of using a loop, this solution seems pretty ideal to me: It is concise, it is readable, it is efficient. I don't think it can be more concise; readability always is debatable.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt #1 is closer to your goal ;)

- you are right that you can use `while` and `for` (and probably other kinds of processing multiple numbers, but that just for the sake of completeness, forget it for now)
- your `println` (or `print`) should be within the loop because you want to print more than just one number.
- in you current attempt #1 you end your loop with the first odd number: 1 This doesn't count up very far ;)

So you have to use an `if` inside your loop where you check the result of `isOdd(number)` and only print if it's odd.
But the loop has only the upper bound limit as condition (`number < 100`) as you want to check all the numbers.

Smartass hint (try it only after your program works fine): if you count up by 2 instead by 1 (`number = number + 2;`), your program will only need half the time - and you could even skip the `isOdd` check ;-)